# OMDb API not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I am using [OMDb API](http://www.omdbapi.com/) to fetch Title, Year and Runtime of movie. These should appear on the page as soon as it loads.I used j query ajax for this. But it does not work.

As soon as the page loads it shows undefined written there. Where I am making the mistake??

I am new to j query ajax and API's so any help would be appreciated.Thanks in advance :)

```html
<! doctype html>
 <html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

 <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script      src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"><  </script>
   
<script type="text/javascript">
  
  window.onload=function()
    {
  $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=spiderman&y=&plot=full&r=json",
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "json",
        success: fetch
    }); 
}
    //For fetching data on success
   function fetch(e){      
    var result="";
    $.each(e,function(value){
  
         result+="<p>" +value.Title +"</p>"; 
         result+="<p>" +value.Year +"</p>";
         result+="<p>" +value.Runtime +"</p>";   
       
    });
    $('#movie').html(result); //For storing result in html
   }   
</script> 
 
</head>
      
<body>
  <p id="movie"></p>
  
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to get all returned values from the object, you need to get each property by key and value,the returned json looks like this:

```
{"Title":"Spiderman","Year":"1990","Rated":"N/A","Released":"N/A","Runtime":"5 min","Genre":"Short","Director":"Christian Davi","Writer":"N/A","Actors":"N/A","Plot":"N/A","Language":"German","Country":"Switzerland","Awards":"N/A","Poster":"N/A","Metascore":"N/A","imdbRating":"5.7","imdbVotes":"90","imdbID":"tt0100669","Type":"movie","Response":"True"}
```

so just call `e.Title` to get title or loop into object using $.each with key and value as arguments.
first argument is the property name(KEY) and second is the value.

```
$.each(e,function(key,value){
     result+="<p>"+ key + " : " + value +"</p>";         
});
```

```html
<! doctype html>
 <html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

 <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script      src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"><  </script>
   
<script type="text/javascript">
  
  window.onload=function()
    {
  $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=spiderman&y=&plot=full&r=json",
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "json",
        success: fetch
    }); 
}
    //For fetching data on success
   function fetch(e){      
    var result="";
       //where keys are attribute names and values are their values
       $.each(e,function(key,value){
          result+="<p>"+ key + " : " + value +"</p>"; 
             
       }); 
    
    $('#movie').html(result); //For storing result in html
   }   
</script> 
 
</head>
      
<body>
  <p id="movie"></p>
  
 </body>
```

Comment: Thank u this worked but can u please explain I couldn't understand.

Comment: @shuchi, I edited the answer, now you can loop to get all returned values and their corresponding key, hope it helps.